# $TemplateCache or TemplateUrl for directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have $http.get all the html templates into the $TemplateCache, my question is for my directives is it more efficient to use

```
TemplateUrl : abc.html
```

or

```
Template : $TemplateCache.get('abc.html')?
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`templateUrl` will request the html for the first time and will put it in templateCache, so only the first time you will have the hit to the server and NOT for each time.

`templateCache` would avoid that hit even for the first time.

you can use [this grunt](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-angular-templates)  to put all your templates at once in the template cache, to avoid hitting server for each template. This would make it much more efficient.

Comment: the angular logic is like below (a) check if templateUrl is present in templateCache if yes serve it from here (b) if not, then make request to server then add it to cache and server from cache... so once the template is added to cache all the subsequent request would be served from cache...